When generating a ADLS SAS token, specifying the path causes an authorization failure
I use following code to generate SAS token, when path is null or empty string, it's working.
TokenCredential tokenCredential =
    new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
        .tenantId(tenantId)
        .clientId(clientId)
        .clientSecret(clientSecret)
        .build();

DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient =
    new DataLakeServiceClientBuilder()
        .endpoint(endpoint)
        .credential(tokenCredential)
        .buildClient();

UserDelegationKey userDelegationKey =
    dataLakeServiceClient.getUserDelegationKey(start, expiry);

PathSasPermission pathSasPermission =
    PathSasPermission.parse("rwdlca");
DataLakeServiceSasSignatureValues signatureValues =
    new DataLakeServiceSasSignatureValues(expiry, pathSasPermission);

String sasToken =
    new DataLakeSasImplUtil(signatureValues,container, path, true)
        .generateUserDelegationSas(userDelegationKey, accountName, Context.NONE);

However, when I specify path, it will fail. I get error message below.
Status code 403
<Error>
<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
<Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.</Message>
</Error>

I give path data/testTable, and do sql execution
sql("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + namespaceName);
sql(String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (id bigint COMMENT 'unique id',data string, ts timestamp) USING iceberg " + "PARTITIONED BY (bucket(2, id), days(ts))", tableName));
sql(String.format(" INSERT INTO %s VALUES (1, 'a', cast('2023-10-01 01:00:00' as timestamp));", tableName));
sql(String.format(" INSERT INTO %s VALUES (2, 'b', cast('2023-10-02 01:00:00' as timestamp));", tableName));
sql(String.format(" INSERT INTO %s VALUES (3, 'c', cast('2023-10-03 01:00:00' as timestamp));", tableName));

Diagnostic for failed authentication requests
I also try to use Diagnostic for failed authentication requests function in Azure portal, but seems it do nothing.
---Updated---
Code use for generate token
Token genarated by path new DataLakeSasImplUtil(signatureValues, "container", path, true)
Postman fail
My container in azure portal
My Access Role
Token genarated without path new DataLakeSasImplUtil(signatureValues, "container", "", true)
And then change request url to fetch file.
Postman success when sas token is generate without path

Can you add full code with how you are creating sas token?.

Sorry, I add more information, does this work for you?

Check the below answer.


When generating a ADLS SAS token, specifying the path causes an authorization failure

The above error occurs when you pass incorrect permissions or credentials to access the Azure data lake storage Account.
In my environment, I added Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the Azure data lake gen2 storage account.
Portal:

In my environment, I stored files in the foo/bar directory like below.
Portal:

You can use the below code that will generate sas token for path using Azure Java SDK.
Code:
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.*;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.implementation.util.DataLakeSasImplUtil;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.models.*;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.sas.DataLakeServiceSasSignatureValues;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.sas.PathSasPermission;
import com.azure.core.util.Context;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class App {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // Replace with your details
       String tenantId = "";
       String clientId = "";
       String clientSecret = "";
       String accountName = "venkat8912";
       String containerName = "test";
       String path = "foo/bar"; // Path within the container
       String endpoint = String.format("https://%s.dfs.core.windows.net", accountName);

       OffsetDateTime start = OffsetDateTime.now();
       OffsetDateTime expiry = OffsetDateTime.now().plusHours(1); // Token expiry (1 hour)

       try {
          
           ClientSecretCredential tokenCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                   .tenantId(tenantId)
                   .clientId(clientId)
                   .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                   .build();

           DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient = new DataLakeServiceClientBuilder()
                   .endpoint(endpoint)
                   .credential(tokenCredential)
                   .buildClient();

           UserDelegationKey userDelegationKey = dataLakeServiceClient.getUserDelegationKey(start, expiry);

           PathSasPermission pathSasPermission = new PathSasPermission()
                   .setReadPermission(true)
                   .setWritePermission(true)
                   .setDeletePermission(true)
                   .setListPermission(true)
                   .setCreatePermission(true)
                   .setAddPermission(true);

           DataLakeServiceSasSignatureValues signatureValues = new DataLakeServiceSasSignatureValues(expiry, pathSasPermission);

           String sasToken = new DataLakeSasImplUtil(signatureValues, containerName, path, true)
                   .generateUserDelegationSas(userDelegationKey, accountName, Context.NONE);

           String fullPathUrl = String.format("%s/%s/%s?%s", endpoint, containerName, path, sasToken);
           System.out.println("Full Path URL with SAS Token: " + fullPathUrl);

       } catch (Exception ex) {
           System.err.println("Error generating SAS token: " + ex.getMessage());
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}

Output:
Full Path URL with SAS Token: https://venkat8912.dfs.core.windows.net/test/foo/bar?sv=2023-11-03&se=2024-12-13T05%3A34%3A32Z&skoid=xxxx15&sktid=93xxxx6d&skt=2024-12-13T04%3A34%3A32Z&ske=2024-12-13T05%3A34%3A32Z&sks=b&skv=2023-11-03&sr=d&sp=racwdl&sdd=2&sig=redacted


Now, I used the above file URL and fetched the files which is stored in that path of Azure Data Lake Storage account.
Output:

Update:
The above code with DataLakeServiceclient will work on Data Lake gen2 storage accounts.

I give it path data/test/iceberg_rest_dml/test, and genarated token sdd is 4.
But my sql execution will modify file at data/test/iceberg_rest_dml/test/data and data/test/iceberg_rest_dml/test/metadata.
Is this the reason AuthenticationFailed?

Yeah, may be Have you checked the generated token like me with postman?

Yes, the result is still AuthenticationFailed. I've update some picture. I believe the operation is right.

Seems the problem is not sdd. Is that something to do with account setting? Or some version has issue?

You mentioned successful output in that what is the difference you mentioned there also path url.

It will only success when I generate token without specify path

new DataLakeSasImplUtil(signatureValues, "container", "", true)

First I generate sas token without path. And then I change real request path to where my file is.

I used same above code with String path = "foo/bar/sample"; and I got the output:
https://i.imgur.com/2u93E9u.png

Have you tried the exact code in your environment?

Yes I use the same code.

https://i.imgur.com/7GQs0Jp.png see here i got the exact output and it worked.

Can you share the screenshot of your code with output?

My full code is here (this version is work, without specify path)
https://github.com/apache/gravitino/pull/5737/files#diff-ac6f4104aaaca102b1a44d4d99c446874b4c0d594831a87ccb790d51962b6836

Have you tried with exact code in your environment with path is it working?

This is my screenshot.
https://imgur.com/a/JVFD1DE

I will try to use your code exactly same, and update a screenshot

In your code your not separating container and path that makes an difference try this
String path = "test/foo/bar/sample"  
String container = path.split("/")[0]; // Extract container name
String blobPath = path.substring(path.indexOf("/") + 1); // Extract blob path```

I've try exactly the same. And still fail.

https://imgur.com/a/qS12wgZ

My sdk version is below:
azure-identity = "1.13.1"
azure-storage-file-datalake = "12.20.0"
azure-core-http-okhttp = "1.12.0"
java8

I used the same code with https://i.imgur.com/mZtrFla.png and with same https://i.imgur.com/idJPj6m.png and output: https://i.imgur.com/SNYAPgd.png

Also, can you try with new project and folder with same exact code.

Maybe is because I use okhttp.
implementation(libs.azure.identity) {
exclude(group = "com.azure", module = "azure-core-http-netty")
}
implementation(libs.azure.storage.file.datalake) {
exclude(group = "com.azure", module = "azure-core-http-netty")
}
implementation(libs.azure.core.http.okhttp)
I will try to use same env as yours.
Really thans for spending time with me.

Yes, I will try.

Turns out, the problem is my project environment.
It's very frustrating, and I really appreciate your time.

Thanks again, you guys really save my life. I am so happy that finally figure this out

Hey, Iam here to update real problem I found.
At first I thought is because my project environment, but actually is beacuse I didn't upgrade my storage account to ADLS gen 2, so sas token credentail will fail.

Could you update this info in your answer? So that people could be helped
